# Perl IO::Socket::UNIX DGRAM non-blocking socket blocks in a loop

Tags: perl, sockets, nonblocking, epoll, datagram

Having an issue with socket block which I defined to be non-blocking.

This way I make a new socket:

```
   unlink "/tmp/mysock";
   $socket = IO::Socket::UNIX->new(Local => "/tmp/mysock",
                                   Type      => SOCK_DGRAM,
                                   )
   or die "SOCKET CREATION FAILED: $!\n";
   $socket->blocking(0);

   $client = IO::Socket::UNIX->new(Peer => "/tmp/mysock",
                                   Type => SOCK_DGRAM
                                  )
   or die "CLIENT SOCKET: $!\n";
   $client->blocking(0);
```

This is how I send message from thread#1:

```
while ( $client->send(pack("LLLL", $_[0], $_[1], $_[2], $_[3]).join(':', @_[4..$#_]), 0) eq undef)
{
    #Error logging here
}
$client->flush();
```

This is how I receive the message in thread#2

```
while (1)
{
    my $fds=epoll_wait($poll, 10000, -1) or next; # next when error

    foreach my $fd (@{$fds})
    {
        if ($fd->[0] == fileno($socket))
        {

            while ($socket->recv($msg,64,0))
            {
                #Processing the message
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is despite the fact that either `$socket` or `$client` are defined to be non-blocking the `$socket` blocks in the `while ($socket->recv($msg,64,0))` loop until the next message comes.
Am I missing anything here?
What can I do to avoid this blocking?

Thanks in advance!
:)

**UPDATE**

This way it works:

```
use Socket;
```

and

```
while ( !defined(send($client,pack("LLLL", $_[0], $_[1], $_[2], $_[3]).join(':', @_[4..$#_]),0)))
{
}
```

and

```
while (defined(recv($server,my $msg,64,0)))
{
}
```

Comment: it probably isn't your issue but the code `$client->send(pack("LLLL", $_[0], $_[1], $_[2], $_[3]).join(':', @_[4..$#_]), 0) eq undef` should instead be `!defined($client->send(pack("LLLL", $_[0], $_[1], $_[2], $_[3]).join(':', @_[4..$#_]), 0))`

Comment: I fixed this both for `send` and `recv`. Seems to work. But I also used `send` and `receive` from `Socket` lib. Anyway, thanks!